# Has Christopher Tolkien said how he would have done "On the Ruin of Doriath" differently?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

The chapter *On the Ruin of Doriath* in *The Silmarillion* is known to have been a rather extensive synthesis by CJRT of JRRT's existing texts (plus a bit of his own creativity), which were less cohesive/inter-consistent than and with the other parts of the Quenta Silmarillion that was being assembled. There are sources and discussions [here](https://www.planet-tolkien.com/board/14/4548/0/the-ruin-of-doriath) and [here](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Of_the_Ruin_of_Doriath). Key quote (emphasis added):

> This story was not lightly or easily conceived, but was the outcome of long experimentation among alternative conceptions. In this work Guy Kay took a major part, and the chapter that I finally wrote owes much to my discussions with him. It is, and was, obvious that a step was being taken of a different order from any other ‘manipulation’ of my father’s own writing in the course of the book: even in the case of the story of The Fall of Gondolin, to which my father had never returned, something could be contrived without introducing radical changes in the narrative. It seemed at that time that there were elements inherent in the story of the Ruin of Doriath as it stood that were radically incompatible with ‘The Silmarillion’ as projected, and that there was here an inescapable choice: either to abandon that conception, or else to alter the story. I think now that this was a mistaken view, and that **the undoubted difficulties could have been, and should have been, surmounted** without so far overstepping the bounds of the editorial function. (from: *HoME XI: The War of the Jewels: "The Tale of Years"*)

The big question is, has CJRT ever indicated how he would have "surmounted" the "undoubted difficulties"? He discusses the various difficulties immediately prior to this passage (quoted in the second posting at [this thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20170619053132/http://www.planet-tolkien.com/board/14/4548/0/the-ruin-of-doriath)), but I haven't read much of the History of Middle-earth, and haven't seen any quotes around the internet of what he might have proposed.

Comment: I think you’ve asked a rather impossible question. I’ve only glanced shortly but it seems like you’ve uncovered the best information there is on the matter in the linked discussions.

Comment: @Edlothiad well the answer might be 'no' :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts No, the shape of the question only allows either "I could not find such a thing" ot an affirmative answer, as that could be pointed out and quoted while silence can't be. But inability to find would need to list where you looked, so it should be a very very extended list.

Comment: @Trish if it doesn’t exist in any of the published works, then the answer _is_ “No”. That being said I find such answers rather tedious and would rather see something like the discussions that were have in the linked boards. This platform, however, doesn’t quite allow for such discussion.

Comment: What if I wrote: "has CJRT ever published something stating how he would have surmounted...."? I don't mean "has he ever voiced an opinion in a discussion somewhere...." etc.

Comment: @DavidRoberts The problem is there is too much that he has said and we don't have access to ALL his notes. He *might* have made a note of it in a tiny limited edition that went only to his friends and family. Or he made a statement in an obscure published magazine, that nobody even remembers but is on file *somewhere* as a microfilm. The core of the problem is in the *anywhere* or *ever* opening the rabbit hole to needing to sift through *all* the sources that he ever created. Which is clearly Too Broad for not researchable or pure speculative value.

Comment: @Trish I believe there's some precedent on this site for questions of the form "Has X ever addressed Y?" being valid, on-topic, sufficiently scoped questions (i.e. questions that are phrased similarly have been left open). This may be worth discussing on Meta (if it hasn't been already), but as it stands I'm not sure the definition of Too Broad you're using matches with the definition the community as a whole uses; how much research is required shouldn't be a consideration.

Comment: @Trish Nothing you describe is Too Broad, not researchable, or purely speculative: it’s well-defined, just very _difficult_ to research fully. But how difficult it is to locate something required to make a definitive answer has no bearing on whether the question is on topic. Even beyond that, there is no rule that questions must be definitively answerable with 100% accuracy to be on topic; many good questions here are not. “Unknown, but probably yes/no based on available sources” is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: Would the down/close voter care to explain? I can focus the attention of the question onto whether CJRT indicated something in the published books (primarily HoME, I guess), rather than asking for arbitrary indications (murmured in his sleep, mentioned offhand to one of his kids over lunch etc...)

Comment: This is not CJRT, but I just learned of the 'Translations from the Elvish' project (http://forum.barrowdowns.com/forumdisplay.php?f=16) that has been going for 17 years (current status: http://forum.barrowdowns.com/showpost.php?p=712207&postcount=194) and is attempting to compile in a consistent way everything non-LR and non-Hobbit into a single narrative (plus 'lore' ~ appendices) from all of published Tolkien. In essence, what CJRT might have done if HoME etc had been done before Silmarillion, with very careful attention to priority of manuscripts etc, and trying to use only JRRT's words

Comment: "§310 (§37a) There {they}[the dwarves] surprised Thingol upon {a}the hunt with but small company of arms {and Thingol was slain} <HoME11; The Tale of The Years{Somehow it must be}for they contrived it that Thingol {is}was lured outside {or induced to go to war beyond} his borders and {is} there {slain by the Dwarves.}> RD-SL-22 <TN the king and his company were all encircled with armed foes. Long they fought bitterly{ there} among the trees, and the {Nauglath}[Naugrim] - for such were their foes - had great scathe of them or ever they were slain. ...

Comment: ...Yet in the end were they all fordone, and {Mablung and} the king[‘s thanes] fell{ side} by[ his] side - but RD-SL-23 <TN, Note 12 {Against this sentence my father wrote a direction that the story was to be that} the {Nauglafring}[Nauglamír] caught in the bushes and held the king>, and Naugladur it was who swept off the head of {Tinwelint}[Thingol] {after he was dead}, for {living}[so long as Thingol could fight] he dared not so near to his bright sword{ or the axe of Mablung}.>" is how it is resolved there. (here {...} means delete, [...] means insert. Ignore codes for sources otherwise)

Comment: And the source for that passage is the post stamped [10-09-2017, 03:57 PM] at http://forum.barrowdowns.com/showthread.php?t=4425&page=3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the passing of CJRT, I believe the answer will now have to be 'no'. I left this open in case it was eventually addressed somewhere, but without a discovery of some very obscurely published commentary we can only surmise or infer from the existing HoME content.

Comment: Apparently Verlyn Flieger once asked CJRT the hard questions about certain parts of the Ruin of Doriath, and he admitted writing particular lines out of whole cloth, for instance the speech Thingol made to the dwarves "O ye of uncouth race..." So presumably passages like these would not have been in any ideal version he later wished he'd written.

Comment: I see CJRT as JRRT's (junior) partner in this great work and CJRT's work as equally definitive, except when it contradicts JRRT's published work. (It's worth remembering that JRRT frequently adopted the conceit that he was but a translator and scholar of old texts.)

Comment: Oh, yes, I agree. But given that CJRT changed his mind, and told us so, and (I believe) figured out a way to stick more closely to what he set as his overall aim for the '77 Silm, I really wish we'd gotten a hint of what that was. It's no worse than JRRT revising chapter 5 of the Hobbit to be more consistent with LotR (though I'm aware that the history of particular update is a little more subtle than that).

Answer (score 8):

This is not really answering the question as stated, but it is in some sense *even better*: it's what **JRR Tolkien** stated was the solution to the problem, in a manuscript Christopher Tolkien apparently never had access to!

In *Concerning ... 'The Hoard'*, a privately-owned 1964 manuscript [recently put up for sale](https://www.jrrtolkien.it/2022/07/04/scoperto-manoscritto-che-cambia-il-silmarillion/), Tolkien wrote that the Girdle of Melian was down either because it was robbed of its power to keep out evil because of evil deeds done *within* (the slaughter of Húrin's band of outlaws by Thingol's soldiers/guards), or because of Melian's grief and horror at this, she let it down herself. Then when the Dwarf army turned up after Thingol reneged on paying for the Nauglamir/Silmaril fusion job (he isn't killed immediately, in this version, contra Christopher's 1977 edition of *The Silmarillion*), they could easily enter Doriath, and Thingol and most of his army was killed.

> [image]
> [image]
> The Dwarves were angered, all the more because they had themselves come under the dragon-spell. They rejected Thingol’s terms, and refused anything less than the full tithe of the treasure of Nargothrond. Unpaid they departed in wrath. Back in their mountain-strongholds, they plotted revenge, and not long after they came down with a great force and invaded Doriath. This had before been impossible, because of the Girdle of Melian, an invisible fence maintained by her power and will through which no one with evil intent could pass. But either this fence had been robbed of its power by the evil within, or Melian had removed it in grief and horror at the deed that had been done. The Dwarf-host entered Doriath and most of Thingol’s warriors perished. His halls were violated and he himself slain.

The story then progresses much as before, this access to Doriath being the crux of Christopher's problem.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding the relevant quote from manuscript. Feel free to revert if needed.

Comment: @ibid Thanks. There's a slight concern about copyright here (the Estate still controls this, despite it being privately owned, apparently), but I'm willing to claim this comes under a reasonable Fair Use case (addressing the four pillars of US Fair Use: it's a small sample, it's for the purposes of academic analysis, it won't affect commercial opportunities, and the text has been made public before)